# How to sort a complex column in Datatables according to a property of the data item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have this datatable, listing persons. The first column contains 3 attributes of a person: `<td>[title] [lastName] [firstName]</td>`.

So for example if the data is:

```
[
    {
        "firstName":"Foo",
        "lastName":"Bar",
        "title":"Z"
    },
    {
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Doe",
        "title":"A"
    }
];
```

Then when sorted ascending, the rows will be by default:

```
A Doe John
Z Bar Foo
```

("A" before "Z")

But instead of this default string sorting based on the whole cell content, I want it to be based on `lastName`. In that case, the ascending sorting I expect is:

```
Z Bar Foo
A Doe John
```

("Bar" before "Doe")

I tried to do it like this:

```
var persons = [
    {
        "firstName":"Foo",
        "lastName":"Bar",
        "title":"Z"
    },
    {
        "firstName":"John",
        "lastName":"Doe",
        "title":"A"
    }
];

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnSortData["first-column"] = function (oSettings, iColumn) {
    return jQuery.map(oSettings.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings), function (tr, i) {
        return persons[i].lastName;
    });
};

$("table").dataTable({
    "aaData":persons,
    "aoColumns":[
        {
            "sTitle":"First column",
            "mData":function (source, type, val) {
                return source.title + " " + source.lastName + " " + source.firstName;
            },
            "sSortDataType":"first-column"
        }
    ]
});
```

Corresponding jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Gsb3/1/

But this custom sorting doesn't work - it remains by the first letter of the cell, which is `title`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting by surname if first and lastname are in the same field datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40770651/sorting-by-surname-if-first-and-lastname-are-in-the-same-field-datatable)

Answer (score -1):

Just looking at your code, it seems you are using datatable, why dont you use the sorting functionality provided by datatable.

```
$("table").dataTable({
  "aaData":persons,
  "aaSorting": [[1, 'desc']]
  ]
});
```

Datatable is 0 based, so this will sort the table when loaded for the 2nd column of the table to be descending default.

Source: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Comment: Your solution works, but I don't understand why - there is only 1 column in my example.

Comment: Also, why `desc`? I want to sort by last name ascending.

Comment: then set it to asc :D

Comment: Sorry I wrote too fast when I mentioned that your solution works. There is only 1 column in my question, as you can see in the jsFiddle.

Comment: if you are displaying the informations in one column, i would suggest you format the json before sending to the front end to play with